# FluentValidation NullReferenceException - Way to prevent checking for null values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

If I have something like this:

```
When(x => x.SendMail.Equals("Y"), () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
});
```

and `SendMail` does not have a value, I will get a `NullReferenceException`. However, if I surround the `When()` like so:

```
When(x => x.SendMail != null, () =>
{
    When(x => x.SendMail.Equals("Y"), () =>
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
    });
});
```

it works as I would expect and I do not get a NRE when `SendMail` does not have a value. I'm new to FluentValidaton and C# in general. Is this the proper way to go about handling validations like this? Do I need to wrap all logic like this with null checks?

Comment: Are you able to do `When(x => x.SendMail != null && x.SendMail.Equals("Y"),...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just switch the comparison.

```
When(x => x.SendMail.Equals("Y"), () => // etc
```

becomes

```
When(x => "Y".Equals(x.SendMail), () => // etc
```

This works because "Y" is never `null` (*so the `Equals` method can be called which is where your current code fails*) and will also not throw an NRE when doing a comparison inside of the `Equals` method as a `null` value will simply return `false`.

Comment: I like this answer. I am wondering now if `object.Equals("Y", x.SendMail)` is also a good option?

Comment: @Nkosi - I don't see why not or `string.Equals` as well if the OP wanted to do a case insensitive comparison by including a `StringComparison` parameter.

Comment: That makes sense. wasn't sure if `"Y"` was a mcve stand in.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to do something like this

```
When(x => x.SendMail != null && x.SendMail.Equals("Y"), () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
});
```

This way second condition of and statement (`x.SendMail.Equals("Y")`) evaluates only if first one (`x.SendMail != null`) is true. 
This rule it works for any boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing can be simplified to

```
When(x => x.SendMail != null && x.SendMail.Equals("Y"), () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
});
```

Or if using latest version c#

```
When(x => x.SendMail?.Equals("Y") ?? false, () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Buening you are trying to call instance method of null object so you are getting  NullReferenceException and this is normal for c#. I think you could use null conditional operator from c#6

```
When(x => x.SendMail?.Equals("Y"), () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.To).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.From).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty();
});
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat what others have posted long before your answer